# Accessing nested index in v-for (select)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an object structred as follows:

```
{
  "cad_id": "547",
  "dropdowns": [
    {
      "dropdown_id": "6",
      "table_name": "ambulances",
      "column_name": "ambulance",
      "value": "G3,G4,G5,R1"
    },
    {
      "dropdown_id": "7",
      "table_name": "ambulances",
      "column_name": "hospital_name",
      "value": "Royal Free,Royal Free Cath Lab,Royal Free Maternity,UCH,Barnet,Barnet Marternity"
    }
  ],
  "responders": [
    {
      "type": "ambulance",
      "id": "41",
      "cad_id": "547",
      "ambulance": "G3",
      "call_sign_1": null,
      "call_sign_2": null,
      "call_sign_3": null,
      "call_sign_4": null,
      "incident_arrival_time": null
    }
  ]
}
```

In the HTML (view), I would like to display a select dropdown that has the options populated from the `value` key in the `dropdowns` array. It should then show the selected option as the one matching in the `ambulance` key in the `responders` array.

This is the Vue code I tried, but I keep getting an error saying `x` is not defined (in the v-for inside the select):

```
<section v-for="(i, index) in responders">
    <select class="form-control" v-model="i.ambulance">
        <option value="">--Please Select--</option> 
        <section v-for="x in dropdowns" v-if="x.table_name == 'ambulances' && x.column_name == 'ambulance'">
            <option v-for="option in x.value.split(',')" :value="option">{{ option }}</option>
        </section>
    </select>       
</section>
```

PS. I am aware the data is not structured in the best way, however I have no control to change this from the server.

Comment: What v-for is causing an errror? in a section or in an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually resolved this myself. The issue is using a `<section>` tag inside a select. You have to use `<optgroup>`instead:

```
<section v-for="(i, index) in responders" :key="index">
    <select class="form-control" v-model="i.ambulance">
      <option value>--Please Select--</option>
      <optgroup
                v-for="dropdown in dropdowns"
                :key="dropdown.value"
                v-if="dropdown.table_name == 'ambulances' && dropdown.column_name == 'ambulance'"
                >
        <option
                v-for="option in dropdown.value.split(',')"
                :value="option"
                :key="option"
                >{{ option }}</option>
      </optgroup>
    </select>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

**it is not recommended to use v-for and v-if in the same component**,

it is better to use a **computed property** to filter the elements and then make a **v-for on the computed property**

```
{
    computed: {
        filteredItems() {
            return this.dropdowns.filter(x => x.table_name == 'ambulances' && x.column_name == 'ambulance') //your condition
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Although this is a valid point, it doesn't actually help me with the question of attempting to use a nested loop with a Select element

Answer (score 0):

```
I think the section tag is not supported in select tag.
Only optgroup or option tag is available in the tag.

<section v-for="(i, index) in responders" :key="index">
    <select class="form-control" v-model="i.ambulance">
      <option value>--Please Select--</option>
      <optgroup
                v-for="dropdown in dropdowns"
                :key="dropdown.value"
                v-if="dropdown.table_name == 'ambulances' && dropdown.column_name == 'ambulance'"
                >
        <option
                v-for="option in dropdown.value.senter code hereplit(',')"
                :value="option"
                :key="option"
                >{{ option }}</option>
      </optgroup>
    </select>
  </section>
```